# How to add Entity Framework column value depends from other column value?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-migrations

I use entity framework core, generate migrations based on DbContext.
One of my entity in database is:

```
class Metadata
{
    public int Id { get; set }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndData { get; set; }
}
```

Valid case id EndDate > StartDate
How to configure values dependency in EntityFramework builder:

```
public class MetadataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Metadata>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Metadata> builder)
    {...}
}
```

Required condition is

```
StartDate <= EndDate
```

Comment: Your question is inadequate! Please explain thoroughly what exactly you are wanting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Foolproof validation library that is available on Codeplex:

https://foolproof.codeplex.com/

It supports validation attributes:

```
[Is]
[EqualTo]
[NotEqualTo]
[GreaterThan]
[LessThan]
[GreaterThanOrEqualTo]
[LessThanOrEqualTo]
```

-

```
[Required]
[GreaterThan("StartDate" , ErrorMessage="your message")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you @AmirNorouzpour, but DataAnnotationis not my solution. I need IEntityTypeConfiguration